# Parse Mailman Archive

Tags: python, regex

I'm currently trying to parse a Mailman txt-archive file. These files are have all emails sent over the list concatenated in one file. The structure is like this:

```
From SOMETHING
From: SOMETHING
Date: SOMETHING
Subject: SOMETHING
In-Reply-To: SOMETHING
Message-ID: <SOMETHING>

CONTENT



From SOMETHING
From: SOMETHING
Date: SOMETHING
Subject: SOMETHING
In-Reply-To: SOMETHING
Message-ID: SOMETHING

CONTENT


[...]
```

The problem is that `CONTENT` could contain newlines. So I can't simply split the archive in messages and then parse each message.

My try to parse this was:

```
def parseContent(content):
    import re
    pattern = r"From (.*)\n"+\
               "From: (.*)\n"+\
               "Date: (.*)\n"+\
               "Subject: (.*)\n"+\
               "In-Reply-To: (.*)\n"+\
               "Message-ID: (.*)\n"+\
               "(.*)"
    matches = re.findall(pattern, content)

    for from1, from2, date, subject, inreply, messageid, body in matches:
        print from1
        print body
        print "#"*20
    return matches
```

But `body` doesn't contain the body of the message, but only one newline. How can I make the last matching group to match everything, but as soon as the part above would match, the body matching group should not match?

Comment: Is there a distinct delimiter between messages? eg `\n\n` or similar?

Comment: I'm not sure about this. I think that `\n\n` is always between messages, but the problem is that it might also be within the body.

Comment: So in theory you could have an email that contains the 6 header lines _in the content_ right? I don't know if there's any robust way to parse this...

Comment: @Shep: Oh, you're right ... ok, but I'd say that this is very unlikely (whereas many newlines are likely). So it should parse as many messages as possible and the whole archive should be "matched". So when I concatenate the matched parts, I should be able to get the original archive back.

Comment: One way to do this would be to match with the regex I gave above, search, take the message-ids, split 6 lines above the message-id line. Then you would have single messages and could quite easily parse the rest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two options here:

1. There is a standard library module that opens, reads and writes mailman archives. The [`mailbox`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mailbox.html) module is the one you want, in particular [`mailbox.mbox`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/mailbox.html#mbox) looks like it should be the one you want.
2. In a mailman archive, every message starts with the string `\nFrom`. This will never occur in the body of a message, as the `From` string will be prefixed by a greater than symbol (`>`). Note that the message headers (the lines with the colons) are defined by RFC-2822, and are not part of the mailbox format. I believe that the RFC does not specify any particular order for the message headers.